# Proof of simple linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, proof

> Use this: 
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X}_n) &= 0  \\ 
> \bar{u}_{n} &=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}
> \end{align}
>   To prove this:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X}_n)(\beta_i(X_i-\bar{X}_i)+u_i-\bar{u}_n)=\beta\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X}_n)^{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)u_i$$

However, instead I get:
$$\beta\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X}_n)^{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)u_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)\bar{u}_n$$

Why doesn't $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)u_i=0$, but $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)\bar{u}_n=0$ does? And how do I make $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)\bar{u}_n=0$ disappear?

Comment: Hint: think about why we may pull $\bar{u}_n$ before the summation sign, but not $u_i$.

Comment: What is $u$?  Please define the terms and symbols you use.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I have added it to the main text now.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Is it because $\bar{u}_{n}$ is a constant, while $u_{i}$ is not?

Comment: Yes, that is right - for $\bar{u}_n$ the average has already been taken over $i$, so it is constant with respect to $i$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Why wouldn't $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)u_i$ be zero as well, as wouldn't $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)u_i$ be zero for $u_{1}, u_{2}, ..., u_{i}$? Multiplying zero for every number in the sequence would be zero, wouldn't it?

Comment: What do you believe to be zero in the term you mention? My comments (or the answer below) have no implications for, e.g., $\sum_iX_iu_i$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck The "$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X}_n)$" term

Comment: Yes, but the fact that, say, $2-1-1=0$ does not imply that, say, $2\cdot2-1\cdot(-2)-1\cdot1$ would be zero. You have to multiply out the brackets.

Comment: In general, the error term would be zero right? Does it mean that $\bar{u}_n$ is zero here?

Comment: No, the error term may be (rightly or wrongly) assumed to have *expectation* zero, $E(u_i)=0$. That is a totally different statement to saying that $u_i=0$ for all $i$. If that were true, the relationship between $X$ and $y$ would be deterministic.

Comment: Alright. Then I don't think I know anymore why or have any additional thoughts about $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X}_n)\bar{u}_n=0$ holds.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: This question now meets our standards, & so should be considered on topic.

Comment: @gung I am new to this forum. What large difference did your editing to do my post?

Comment: I didn't mean for it to be too dramatic, @Mataunited17. I just highlighted the original question as a quote. You can do that with `>`. That makes the original question you were asked distinct from the question you are asking here about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $\overline{u}_n$ is a constant not depending on $i$. Hence you can write $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X}_n)\overline{u}_n = \overline{u}_n (\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X}_n))$ and use that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X}_n) = 0$ which gives you $\overline{u}_n * 0 =0$

To answer the questions you were asking in the comments, I'll try to explain in a very detailed way, but most of it was already said in the comments somehow.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X}_n)\overline{u}_n= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\overline{u}_n - \sum_{i=1}^n\overline{X}_n\overline{u}_n=\overline{u}_n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - \overline{u}_n\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{X}_n=\\ \overline{u}_n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - \overline{u}_nn\overline{X}_n=\overline{u}_nn\overline{X}_n - \overline{u}_nn\overline{X}_n=0$$
The first equalitiy is just multiplying out. The second equalitiy holds because $\overline{u}_n$ is a constant (not depending on $i$). The third equalitiy holds becaus $\overline{X}_n$ also does not depend on $i$, hence it is just summed $n$ times. The fourth equality holds because the sum of the $X_i$'s is just $n$ times their mean. The fifths is clear. Now let's consider the other sum.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X}_n)u_i=\sum_{i=1}^nX_iu_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{X}_nu_i = \sum_{i=1}^nX_iu_i-\overline{X}_{n}\sum_{i=1}^nu_i = \\ \sum_{i=1}^nX_iu_i-\overline{X}_{n}n\overline{u}_n = n\overline{(Xu)_n}-n\overline{X}_{n}\overline{u}_n \neq 0 \quad \text{(in general)}$$
The first equality is just multiplying out. The second hold because $\overline{X}_n$ does not depend on $i$. The third equality holds because the sum of the $u_i$'s is just $n$ times their mean. The fourth equation is rewriting the sum of the $X_i$ times $u_i$, as $n$ times their mean $\overline{(Xu)_n} := (X_1u_1+X_2u_2 + \ldots +X_nu_n)/n$ and since $\overline{(Xu)_n} \neq \overline{X}_{n}\overline{u}_n$ (e.g. $\frac{1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6}{3} = 10.666 \neq 10 =\frac{1+2+3}{3} * \frac{4+5+6}{3}$) the last inequality follows.

Comment: Thank you, @Schlaftablette! That is a great explanation of my problem.

Comment: However, I am wondering something about $\overline{u}_n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, why is $\overline{u}_n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=n\bar{Xu}_{n}$ true? Isn't the definition of $\bar{X}_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$? or wouldn't $\sum_{i=1}^nu_{i}=nu_{i}$?